# PHP flatfile storage

Tags: php, database, library

So, I made a tiny (~2 KB, <100 lines) library for simple flat-file data storage.

How it works is, you define a file to be used, and then you can add/read/modify/delete objects as "keys" to/from the file.

All the code is on [github](https://github.com/rahuldottech/varDx), but I'll put it here too:

**`varDx.php`:**

```
<?php
namespace varDX;

class cDX {
    private $dataFile;  

    public function def($filename){
        $this->dataFile = $filename;
    }

    public function write($varName, $varVal){
        if(file_exists($this->dataFile)){
            $foundLine = $this->check($varName);
        } else {
            $foundLine = false;
        }

        if(!$foundLine){
            $writeData = $varName.'__=__'.urlencode(serialize($varVal)).PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents($this->dataFile, $writeData, FILE_APPEND);    
        } else {
            return "ERR_DX_KEY_ALREADY_EXISTS";
        }
    }

    public function read($varName){
        if(file_exists($this->dataFile)){
            foreach(file($this->dataFile) as $line) {
                if(strpos($line, $varName) !== false) {
                    list(, $new_str) = explode("__=__", $line);
                    $foundLine = true;
                }
            }
            if($foundLine){
                $val = rtrim($new_str); 
                return unserialize(urldecode($val));
            } else {
                return "ERR_DX_KEY_NOT_FOUND";
            }
        } else {
            return "ERR_DX_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST";
        }
    }


    public function del($varName){
        if(file_exists($this->dataFile)){
            $f = $this->dataFile;
            $term = $varName.'__=__';
            $arr = file($f);
            foreach ($arr as $key=> $line) {
                if(stristr($line,$term)!== false){unset($arr[$key]);break;}
            }
            //reindexing array
            $arr = array_values($arr);
            //writing to file
            file_put_contents($f, implode($arr));
        } else {
            return "ERR_DX_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST";
        }
    }

    public function modify($varName, $varVal){
        if(file_exists($this->dataFile)){   
            if($this->check($varName)){
                $this->del($varName);
            } 
        }
        $writeData = $varName.'__=__'.urlencode(serialize($varVal)).PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($this->dataFile, $writeData, FILE_APPEND);    

    }

    public function check($varName){
        if(file_exists($this->dataFile)){
            foreach(file($this->dataFile) as $line) {
                if(stripos($line, $varName.'__=__') === 0){
                    return true;
                } 
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return "ERR_DX_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST";
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php
require 'varDx.php';
$dx = new \varDx\cDX; //create object
$dx->def('file1.txt'); //define data file

$a = "this is a string";
$dx->write('val1', $a); //write key to file

$dx->modify('val1', "this is another string"); //modify value of key
echo $dx->read('val1'); //read value of key

if($dx->check('val1')){ //check if key exists
    del('val1'); //delete key
}
```

**File storage:**

All keys are stored in this format:

```
keyname__=__urlencode(serialize(value_of_key))
```

There's more info on the functions in the README on the github page. I'm wondering if I can make this more efficient when dealing with files, and if there's anything else that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of this storage?

Comment: Your library does not adhere to PSR; it can not be installed by composer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code is solely for learning purpose, there are several main issues

- to be honest, a function that returns ERR_DX_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST when I request an object looks a bit weird. I don't even know how to use it. Should I wrap every call to a function in a condition that checks the returned value? Or what else I am supposed to do with this string? Consider using errors/exceptions in case of error.
- a race condition issue. you can have this file malformed if two parallel processes would try to write at the same time. Consider use file locks
- an obvious memory issue - the bigger the file is, the more RAM does it take to process. PHP can let you to read a file line by line without memory overhead
- such a clumsy format as `keyname__=__urlencode(serialize(value_of_key))` doesn't seem to be very reliable. For such a toy storage I would rather use json format, to ease the search/key access.

Comment: The reason I used that weird long return value is because I can't return something like `false` or `0` because those could totally be valid values for the keys being accessed

Comment: I understand that. it desn't make sense to use such weird return value either. there are errors/exceptions to handle this situation

Comment: Cheers! Still new to this stuff, I'll figure something out.